# How to sort a table by multiple columns using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have an unsorted Table A.

```
C1    C2    C3      C4
----------------------    
15      2     7      5
12      5     4      8
19      1     3     12
21      9     1     18
 4     11    12     22
```

I want to sort this table in such a way that values with higher c1, higher c4, higher c2 and lower c3 are on top.

Also, c1 > c2 > c4 > c3 in terms of priority.

I am not sure how to go about this and would really appreciate any help from experts here.

Should I assign a fraction value to each column like c1 = .35 , c2 = .3, c4 = .2, and c3 = .15 and multiply the value for each column by its fraction value and add up all the values for each row?

Comment: I dont get it, what is your expected result after all?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look on "ORDER BY". This should be quite easy...

Comment: Like:21     9     1     18                                                                                               19     1     3     12                                                                                                 12     5     4     8                                                                                                 15     2     7     5                                                                                                                4      11    12    22

Comment: Don't get it. Please edit your question...

Comment: Why would 12 5 4 8 come before 15 2 7 5 ?   Without a full explanation of the logic, no one can help you.

Comment: As @Shnugo said, use the ORDER BY statement... You can specify more columns, as they explain [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need:

```
ORDER BY C1 DESC, C2 DESC, C4 DESC, C3 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean simple order by? Then just add an `order by`clause:

`ORDER BY C1 DESC, C4 DESC, C2 DESC, C3 ASC`

DESC = descending, from highest to lowest
.ASC = ascending, from lowest to highest